# Measures which are constant when not zero

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, singular-measures

Let $S$ be a finite set. I want to consider measures $\mu$ on $S$ which are *constant only when not zero*.

As an example, let $S$ be $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, and take the measure: $\mu(a)=\mu(b)=\mu(e)=1/4,\mu(c)=\mu(d)=0$.

(I'm particularly interested in probability measures with the property above, for example the ones you get from the law of large numbers.)

> The question is: do measures like these have a name?

(The same can be done with any measurable set with a fixed base measure.)

Comment: Maybe "uniform distribution on a (certain) subset" is what you are looking for. In your example, the set is $\{a,b,e\} $. EDIT: Ok, this would be correct if you would only consider probability measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called **discrete** measures (being nonzero on a countable set) and **Dirac** measures (being constant on a set and $0$ everywhere else).

Comment: I mean, is there a name for a measure which is *constant except when it's zero*?

Comment: @geodude It is the Dirac measure. In your example, $\mu$ is the Dirac measure concentrated on the set $\{a,b,e\}$ scaled by $1/4$.

Comment: So do I call it "The Dirac measure for the subset $\{a,b,e\}$"?

Comment: @geodude It is called Dirac measure concentrated on $\{a,b,e\}$.